# How to synchronize sending data to a single data source from two isolated storm clusters

Tags: synchronization, apache-storm, distributed-computing

I have two isolated storm clusters running identical topologies(for failover reasons). I now need to send data to a datasource from only 1 setup at any given time(so that I don't duplicate the data in the sink). Preferably, it should be seamless but I am okay with minimal downtime between the switching.

What synchronization mechanism can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a interesting question.

It's complicated if you only double storm cluster. Because many random factors lead to different computing speed, it's very hard to coordinate.

I think a more practical way is to double the sink(database) as well. Because you do this for failover reason, it's fair to have double sink to skip the complicated problem. And next problem is which database your application should read from. That depends on your scenario, and your application may need add a little feature.

Let's say we have a screen application that only report GMV of a seller. We have a DNS router that pointed to one of the databases. In case of failure or slow computation that caused by data skew, u just need redirect your DNS record pointed to another database. That's very easy. Also that may cause a little problem. Because the different data consuming speed, the GMV may suddenly drop down( Because another cluster haven't computed that many data as the other cluster). That is big issue if the screen is shown to public. So your application need to detect that hold on until the GMV is greater than before(Don't let the number drop).

[image]